# Gitlab only running tests based on changed modules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Lets say I have a test block for all my microservices (15-20+). Tests take a long time since there are so many disparate modules in this monorepo.
Lets say I only want to run 1 or maybe 2 at a time if and only if specific code changes have been made underneath a path. How can I best do this? For assembling I do something like this (not sure if this is terrible or not)

Ultimately, I'm trying to only build and test relevant things if they're relevant (based on if they or a related module I can define change)

## Module-specific assembles

```
x:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:6.0-jdk11
  script:
    - gradle :x:assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - x/build/libs
  only:
    changes:
      - x
      - x/*
      - x/*/**

y_build:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:6.0-jdk11
  script:
    - gradle :y:assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - y/build/libs
  only:
    changes:
      - y
      - y/*
      - y/*/**
```

## Current block for testing

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:6.0-jdk11
  services:
    - name: gitlab-registry.company.com/nap/dynamodb-local:1252954
      command: [ "-inMemory", "-sharedDb" ]
      alias: dynamodb
  script: gradle check
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that a Gitlab CI Pipeline can be triggered, but the basic way is when a commit is pushed, no matter what the change is. Currently, there isn't a way to inspect which parts of the code are changed, and only run some steps or others based on the result, but you can control which steps run based on the branch or tag name.

So for example, you could have steps that only run when the branch name starts with something like "microservice_3_", and then make sure that when editing Microservice 3, you always start the branch name with "microserver_3_", though this could get complicated the more microservices you have to support.

The easier option (in terms of the pipeline definition) is to maintain the microservices in separate repositories, each with their own pipelines and tests. This way each individual pipeline only runs against a specific component and doesn't care about changes to the others. Then if you need to, you can combine the microservices in another repository (included as git submodules) and have a pipeline that only cares about the services as a whole.

This would add extra overhead while developing the project(s), but it makes the pipelines easier to manage.